# Why is my insertion sort faster than mergesort?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, sorting

```rb
# sort.rb
class Array
  def insertion
    (1..self.count).each do |i|
      (i..0).each do |j|
        first = j - 1
        second = j
        if self[second] > self[first]
          swap(second, first)
        end
      end
    end
    self
  end

  def mergesort
    return self if self.size <= 1
    mid = self.size / 2
    left = self[0, mid]
    right = self[mid, self.size-mid]
    merge_array(left.mergesort, right.mergesort)
  end

  # helpers

  def merge_array(left, right)
    sorted = []
    until left.empty? or right.empty?
      if left.first <= right.first
        sorted << left.shift
      else
        sorted << right.shift
      end
    end
    sorted.concat(left).concat(right)
  end

  def swap(previous, current)
    copy = self[previous]
    self[previous] = self[current]
    self[current] = copy
  end
end
```

My rspec file:

```rb
require './sort'

unsorted = 5000.downto(1).to_a.shuffle

describe Array, "#insertion" do
  it "sorts using insertion sort" do
    time = Time.now
    unsorted.insertion.should eq(unsorted.sort)
    puts "insertion"
    puts Time.now - time
  end
end

describe Array, "#merge" do
  it "sorts using merge sort" do
    time = Time.now
    unsorted.mergesort.should eq(unsorted.sort)
    puts "merge"
    puts Time.now - time
  end
end
```

We know that an insertion sort should be slower than a merge sort, because the runtime of the insertion sort is O(n^2) on average, whereas a merge sort is O(n*log(n)). But, when I run the test code above, merge is more than 10 times slower than insertion.

```
insertion
0.001294 seconds

.merge
0.017322 seconds
```

My guess is that I am using some computationally expensive methods like `shift` and `concat`, but having a difference of 10 times is too excessive.

How do I improve the merge sort?

Comment: This could possibly be a better fit on http://codereview.stackexchange.com. See [the FAQ](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq) and see what you think.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I think that's a fair suggestion. Can you move the question? I don't know to.

Comment: I flagged it and asked a moderator to take a look at it. It's a great question for that site. Good luck!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A lot of things here:

1. This is not an insertion sort, it is a bubble sort.
2. `(i..0).each` does nothing, because ranges can't go in reverse order (your spec does not pass). Use `downto` instead.
3. The logic itself is just wrong, if your last index is at the beginning of the string, then you want to swap when the second element is less than the first.
4. Your specs use the same array, but the insertion method mutates the array, so by the time it gets to the merge sort, it has already been sorted.
5. There isn't a good reason to put these on Array (beyond the novelty of it), in general, monkey patching is a bad practice (I'd explain why, but it's sort of beyond the scope of this response).
6. The swap method can be simplified with multiple assignment `self[a], self[b] = self[b], self[a]`.
7. the names `first`, `second`, `previous`, `next`, are all confusing. Their names imply they are elements, but really they are indexes, I'd rename to things like `index1` (maybe `first_index`, but that could get verbose).
8. Why do you switch between `count` and `size`? That is confusing and makes it look like you copied and pasted other people's code (that and the fact that one of the functions mutates the array and the other doesn't, in general, the merge sort looks like it was written by someone who knows what they are doing, and the "insertion" sort does not).
9. The merge sort is probably slower because it creates tons of arrays where it doesn't need to (it has no side effects, but from a performance standpoint, it would be better to just `dup` the array and then sort it in place based on start and end indexes.
10. The tests aren't very useful, because they only sort one array. Say that array is already mostly sorted, then there are very few swaps that the bubble sort has to perform, so it just iterates over the array a bunch of times and it's done.
11. There are environmental differences that can take place between these calls (optimizations, garbage collection status), it's better to use the Benchmark library. It has [`bmbm`](http://rdoc.info/stdlib/benchmark/Benchmark.bmbm) which attempts to minimize these differences.
12. Because you're running the test inside the timer `unsorted.insertion.should eq(unsorted.sort)`, you are not just timing your sort, you're also timing Ruby's `unsorted.sort` as well as the RSpec assertions. It would be better to just wrap the sorting in the timing code, then output the results afterwards.

Comment: Is insertion sort faster for smaller array than merge sort?

Comment: @sp1rs it should be. Consider 2 elements. Insertion sort just compares them, while merge sort, makes a recursive call, and merges

Answer (score 4):

Ideas:

- Try upping your test size to something in the hundreds of thousands and average over a few different arrays since insertion sort is going to be very fast in the best case compared to your merge sort
- Pre-allocate the array in merge rather than building the array dynamically since you should know the size
- Take the correctness (... should) calls out of the time matching

Comment: Almost certainly the repeated internal sorting/comparing in the shoulds are what is killing him.  Also the merge sort implementation creates and destroys a lot of garbage.